# Ignore large or corrupt records when loading files with pig using PigStorage

Tags: apache-pig

I am seeing the following error when loading in a large file using pig.

```
java.io.IOException: Too many bytes before newline: 2147483971
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readDefaultLine(LineReader.java:251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.LineReader.readLine(LineReader.java:176)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.UncompressedSplitLineReader.readLine(UncompressedSplitLineReader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:123)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.initialize(PigRecordReader.java:181)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapReduce.setupNewRecordReader(MRReaderMapReduce.java:157)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapReduce.setSplit(MRReaderMapReduce.java:88)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.initFromEventInternal(MRInput.java:703)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.processSplitEvent(MRInput.java:631)
    at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.input.MRInput.handleEvents(MRInput.java:590)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.handleEvent(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:732)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.access$600(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:106)
    at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask$1.runInternal(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:809)
    at org.apache.tez.common.RunnableWithNdc.run(RunnableWithNdc.java:35)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The command I am using is as follows:

```
LOAD 'file1.data' using PigStorage('\u0001') as (
  id:long,
  source:chararray,
  )
```

Is there any option that can be passed here to drop the record that is causing the issue and continue?

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a certain number of records by using the following setting at the top of your pig script

```
set mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records = 1000;
```

[Link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html): *The number of acceptable skip records surrounding the bad record PER bad record in mapper. The number includes the bad record as well. To turn the feature of detection/skipping of bad records off, set the value to 0. The framework tries to narrow down the skipped range by retrying until this threshold is met OR all attempts get exhausted for this task. Set the value to Long.MAX_VALUE to indicate that framework need not try to narrow down. Whatever records(depends on application) get skipped are acceptable.*